# working with two arrays in foreach, is this example possible?

Tags: php, foreach

I'm working with two arrays, $local and $national. Currently, they're both within their own separate foreach loops, which I'm using as follows:

```php
$list // 1st array
$national // 2nd array
$numberlist = array();
$numbernational = array();

foreach($list as $rows)
{
    // here I have a bunch of code that defines the variable $cheapestdeliverydate
    if(strtotime(date('DjMY', strtotime($_GET['inputDate']))) >= strtotime($cheapestdeliverydate))
    {
        $numberlist[] = $rows;
    }
}

foreach($national as $rows)
{
    // here I have a bunch of code that defines the variable $cheapestdeliverydate
    if(strtotime(date('DjMY', strtotime($_GET['inputDate']))) >= strtotime($cheapestdeliverydate))
    {
        $numbernational[] = $rows;
    }
}
```

Is there a way however to merge these two foreach functions? I've tried the following:

```php
foreach(array_merge($list, $national) as $rows)
{
    if(strtotime(date('DjMY', strtotime($_GET['inputDate']))) >= strtotime($cheapestdeliverydate))
    {
        $numberlist[] = $rows;
        $numbernational[] = $rows;
    }
}
```

But unfortunately when I do a `print_r` on both $numberlist and $numbernational, they're both returning the exact same array. In hindsight this makes sense to me now, so I wonder if I can do something along the lines of:

```
foreach($list as $row, $national as $rows)
{
    if(strtotime(date('DjMY', strtotime($_GET['inputDate']))) >= strtotime($cheapestdeliverydate))
    {
        $numberlist[] = $row;
        $numbernational[] = $rows;
    }
}
```

Both the $list and $national arrays are the same size.

Comment: what error you are getting?
write the format tree of those two arrays

Comment: Is the arrays related in any way? Do they contain the same number of rows? What server error do you get (that type of information is very useful for diagnosing problems, so telling us what error you get can help... the error isn't a state secret is it?)

Comment: If you need to separate the outcome of the foreach in two arrays as you do atm (`numbernational` and `numberlist`) then I would keep two foreach loops since you may want to do something different one day.

Comment: @MarkBaker just edited the question. Both arrays contain the same number of rows. I didn't get a server error this time around so it was maybe my localhost playing up at that particular time. Any thoughts?

Comment: How is `$cheapestdeliverydate` computed? Does it depend on the values from `$list` and/or `$national`?

Comment: @axiac it is quite a long function to compute `$cheapestdeliverydate`, hence why I would like to merge the two. It depends on the values but it's not co-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over both arrays in a single pass using SPL's MultipleIterator

```
$numberlist = [];
$numbernational = [];

$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($list));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($national));
$result = array();
foreach($mi as list($listRow, $nationalRow)) {
    if (strtotime(date('DjMY', strtotime($_GET['inputDate']))) >= strtotime($cheapestdeliverydate)) {
        $numberlist[] = $listRow;
        $numbernational[] = $nationalRow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mark you've come to my rescue several times before. The only problem I have is that currently each foreach has reference to $rows, for example `if ($rows['delivery'] == '1' && $deliverycost != -1) {`. How would I overcome this with the MultipleIterator, because your foreach now reads `foreach($mi as list($listRow, $nationalRow)) {` instead of `foreach($mi as $rows)) {`? Thanks

Comment: Well within the loop, `$listRow` references the row from the `$list` array, while `$nationalRow` references the row from the `$national` array.... you can reference `$listRow['delivery']` and `$nationalRow['delivery']` respectively

Comment: I tried my own version of the MultipleIterator and it failed. You're a genius, the only one that truly understands me. Takes a clever person to downvote, but a genius to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Due to logic of  your code, it must be just

```
$list // 1st array
$national // 2nd array
$numberlist = array();
$numbernational = array();

if(strtotime(date('DjMY', strtotime($_GET['inputDate']))) >= strtotime($cheapestdeliverydate) 
    {
        $numberlist = $list;
        $numbernational = $national;
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Try something like:

```php
$all = array_merge($list, $national);

foreach($all as $rows)
{
    if(strtotime(date('DjMY', strtotime($_GET['inputDate']))) >= strtotime($cheapestdeliverydate))
    {
        $numberlist[] = $rows;
        $numbernational[] = $rows;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly the same as the solution I tried, which doesn't work. The problem is there is no way of differentiating between $numberlist and $numbernational. They both produce the same array, which shouldn't happen.

Comment: Your problem before you edited your post was that you were getting a 500 server error. Please do not change the scope of your questions like that.

Comment: I can change my question how I like, especially if it makes it more relevant. And regardless of whether I got a 500 or not, your answer still isn't valid because it simply repeats what I attempted, which failed.

Comment: It would potentially solve it because the result of the merge would no longer be a temporary variable. Certain hosts or php versions would potentially crash because of that fact.